# How to check stability of a class inferred by Compose compiler?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

There are `@Immutable` and `@Stable` annotations available for developers to mark their classes with. But I'm not quite sure when you need to annotate your classes and when it is inferred automatically. E.g. deeply-immutable data classes seems to be recognized as immutable by default. But you cannot be quite sure unless you log all @Composable calls and see how it behaves. And not knowing what is actually going on is somewhat infuriating for me as a programmer.

I wonder if there are more reasonable ways to see what immutability/stability Compose compiler infers for custom classes?

And if there are no clever ways to check it, what would be the rule of thumb for using `@Immutable` and `@Stable` annotations?

Comment: Somewhat related: the team [is thinking about IDE feedback](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218993617) on Compose's 'stability inference'. Give it a star / comment if you are interested in it as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable the compose compiler metrics to see what the compiler considers is stable. https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).